# Recategorising variable with different scales for regression analysis in R

Tags: r

I'm using R for a University stats project and I'm struggling to find a way to recode an annual 'income' survey variable which has differently sized income brackets:

Under £5,200:        108

£5,200 - £15,599:    487

£15,600 - £25,999:  603

£26,000 - £36,399:   510

£36,400 - £46,799:   395

£46,800 - £74,999:   539

£75,000 - £149,999:  349

£150,000 or more:    100

Is there a way to categorise this, for example using quartiles, so that I can more effectively use it in linear regression?

Thanks!

Edit with what I have so far:

```
levels(bes$y01_Annual)[levels(bes$y01_Annual)=="Not stated"|levels(bes$y01_Annual)=="Don't know"|levels(bes$y01_Annual)=="Prefer not to say"] = NA

bes$y01_Annual = as.numeric(bes$y01_Annual)

quartiles <- quantcut(bes$y01_Annual)
table(quartiles)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In order to get adequate support please provide a minimal reproducible example: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create a data vector with the `median` of each interval , replicated `n` times (`n` being the number of records in that interval)?

It doesn't strictly create a category, as you ask. but might still meet your needs.